# Finding records that match sthg in 2nd of two rows that are part of a set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of parts of words, and each word has two rows. So basically there's a data set of two rows for each word. I want to find words that end in a vowel (in order to later delete them). Here's an example row:

```
ID      wordID  Segment SegType

2475    1170    d       consonant
2476    1170    i       vowel
2477    1171    a       vowel
2578    1171    d       consonant
```

The first two are a bad dataset (wordID 1170) - these I want to find and later delete. The last two are a good dataset (wordID 1171), these I want to keep. To do this, it would be easiest to get a list of `wordID`s and later use them to delete the bad sets.

So how can I select the wordID for each set that ends in a vowel (that is, the second of the two rows of the set has the value `vowel`)? The `ID` of the second part is always higher than of the first part, but not reliable odd or even (I've tried queries using that already).

Comment: The first two are bad means.. are u talking about 1170?

Comment: Yes, I've clarified my question.

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate duplicates? What defines a "bad" wordID?

Comment: Check the solution I posted...

Comment: bad words that those that end in a vowel (where the second of two rows with the same wordID has SegType = "vowel")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select wordId
from t
group by wordId
having max(case when segtype = 'vowel' then id end) = max(id)
```

The `having` clause finds the `id` of the row with a vowel segment for each wordId`and the maximum`id`for each`wordId`.  A`wordId` is in the result set if these ids are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT a.wordID 
FROM words a JOIN words b ON a.wordID = b.wordID
WHERE a.ID > b.ID and a.segType = 'vowel';
```

This basically performs the `SELF JOIN` on `wordID` column and returns all the ids which have higher value than their join counterpart and 'vowel' as segType.

Answer (score 0):

w2 Query - This query is returning the last value for each dataset by grouping on wordID.

w2 is joined with the original table w1(words) on wordID and filtered on last value calculated from the above w2 query.

```
SELECT w1.* 
  FROM words w1
 INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT wordID,LAST_VALUE(SegType) OVER( PARTITION BY wordID ORDER BY id ) AS lv
  FROM words
GROUP BY wordID
) w2
ON w1.wordID = w2.wordID
WHERE w2.lv = 'vowel';
```